# What are some of the pitfalls of reusing a user name in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, active-directory, ubuntu, user-management

First, let me state, this was an IT goof up.  They deleted an account, went "oops" and created a new account with the same credentials.  I can't fathom why.

Regardless, I've got a Linux (Ubuntu Server 10.04) box authenticating against an active directory server, and users logging in have local home directories and such.

I'm stuck with one user name having a new UID (or SID in AD jargon).  ***Over and above `chown`ing his home directory, what other interventions should I do?***

Comment: I think you meant *chown*, rather than *chmod*.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, I did mean `chown`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Search for files/directories owned by the old UID:

```
find / -user <old-uid>
```

Change them if necessary.

Comment: Your describing a method; I'm looking for problems (if any) that doing (something like that) that could create.